# Animating the image in recycler view to fullscreen through dialog box

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

In `RecyclerView`, how can I expand the image such that when we click the `Whatsapp` profile image of others, it shows a complete image in a dialog box? How can I achieve that in `RecyclerView`? with that transaction animation as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use a Dailog Fragment with a single ImageView in the center [Tutorials here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)
2. When the user clicks the recyclerView item, pass the imageView of that specific item to the Dialog Fragment using SharedElementTransition. ( [SharedElementTransition Tutorial here](https://medium.com/@bherbst/fragment-transitions-with-shared-elements-7c7d71d31cbb#.ui253amn5))

   This should do the trick.